# Filtering URLs from text with regex

Tags: regex

So, I have an initial regex filter that I use but I need some more optionality. This works good, but not good enough:

`([a-zA-Z0-9]*\@*)((http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/?\/? ?)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]*)(\.[a-zA-Z]+)(\/\S*)?`

What I want to achieve is to filter these strings:

```
foo@demo.net    
bar.ba@test.co.uk
www.demo.com    
http://foo.co.uk/
http://demo.com/foo.html?q=bar
http://localhost/
```

I also want to filter if there are empty spaces inside the urls like this:

```
foo@demo.net    
bar.ba@test.co.uk
www. demo .com  
http://foo .co. uk/
http:// demo. com/foo.html?q=bar
http://localhost/
```

Comment: just add space in character classes `([a-zA-Z0-9\-\. ]*)(\.[a-zA-Z ]+)`

Comment: Adding spaces will filter more than just urls. I need this to filter chat messages

Comment: Count the spaces in match or count them out ?

Comment: What about removing all the spaces and then run a non greedy regex ?

Comment: I am running regex on a chat message like: `"Hello. I am John. Visit my website www . google . com"` or `"http://www. google.com"`

Comment: @johnnyasda2 What language are you coding in? This is a hard problem and a library to do it probably already exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care what language it's implemented in, [Email::Find](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Find) and [URI::Find](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::Find) already exist and can do what you want.  I wrote them. :)

---

I've implemented this before, and it's a non-trivial problem.  Mixing emails and HTML makes it even harder, I would suggest you do them separately.  I'll discuss just URIs below, but it equally applies to emails.

[URI::Find](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::Find) uses a two pass system.  First it finds likely candidates in the text, then it checks to see if it's actually a URL.  This avoids having to build a complete URI regex, URI validators are available in most languages.  Don't write your own.

Use [the grammar from RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A) to build up a regex of the proper URI character sets strung together in their basic form:

```
URI    = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
```

For example, `scheme` is

```
scheme = ALPHA *( ALPHA / DIGIT / "+" / "-" / "." )
```

Which would be `[A-Za-z]([A-Za-z0-9+-.])*` as a regex.  And so on.

Build the regex in pieces to spare your sanity.

Once you've captured a candidate with your regex, you should run it through an existing URI parser to see if it really is a URI.

[URI::Find has an extensive test suite of false positives and tricky URIs](https://metacpan.org/source/MSCHWERN/URI-Find-20140709/t) you might want to look into.  Running your finder over the RFC itself is also useful.

---

Spaces in URIs are going to be nearly impossible to deal with.  It will greatly increase the number of false positives.

---

Alternatively, you can use the regex from [Regexp::Common::URI](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::URI).  It is very long, so [I've pasted it here](https://gist.github.com/schwern/39c100327f322caa9b5c).  You can also get it with `perl -wle 'use Regexp::Common qw(URI); print $RE{URI}'` after you've installed Regexp::Common.